# Get Individual Values From Foreach Loop and Sum All

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

It's totally a simple thing and got stuck into it for sometime. Here is the scenario - I've a query where I am doing a `Count` with `Group By`. Then iterating it with a `foreach` loop as follows to get individual values:

```
var query = (from c in GetProducts()
             group c by c.Type into g
             select new
             {
               Type = g.Key,
               Count = g.Count()
             });

double value = 0;
double valTotal = 0;

double finalResult = 0;

foreach (var item in query)
{
   value = (((Convert.ToDouble(item.Count)) / 10) * 100); //Getting the count from the above query and this gets individual result set, say grouping category
   valTotal += value; //Trying to do the total of the 'value' result set and this doesn't return the appropriate sum

   finalResult = ((value / valTotal) * 100); Then trying to divide the individual values with the total in the end to get values in percentage
}
```

Example: Getting values from foreach loop and in the value variable, I get - 10, 20, 30, 40. Then sum up them all (10 + 20 + 30 + 40) = 100 and finally again individual result set like (10 / 100) * 100; (20 /100) * 100 and so on. I am expecting to do it in a simple way but seems like missed something here. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

**Note**: `finalResult` variable should return the individual result set finally like this (10 / 100) * 100 = 10%; (20 / 100) * 100 = 20%.

Comment: You give some examples but it's still very unclear. Which of those magic numbers 10, 100 are examples, which are literal?  Can you describe the outcome in terms of Sum and Average (of the Count values)?

Comment: I think that you problem is that `valTotal` is not 100 in you loop for all the `item` in `query` except the last one. You should calculate the `valTotal` separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a list of the IGroupings because we will need it twice:

```
var query = (from ...).ToList();
```

and then a list of percentages is

```
decimal sum = query.Sum(g => g.Count);
var percentages = query
    .Select(g => (g.Count / sum) * 100)  // cast to double/decimal/int as required
    .ToList()
    ;
```

Note that this will add up to very close to 100% but it could be off a little.

---

Additional, assuming Type == Category

```
.Select(g => new {
    Category = g.Key,
    Average = (g.Count / sum) * 100  // cast to double/decimal/int as required
   })
```

Comment: Almost you got me @Henk Holterman. Though I require one more thing with that and need the category name as well with it. Any way I can do that with the query?